# Woocommerce - Button for displaying sold-out products

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Good morning,

We have hidden "out of stock" products in our e-commerce via the Woocommerce settings. We would like to create a button that allows users to display "available" and "out of stock" products together.

Do you know of any plugin that would allow this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you need to manage this property like as the product is in a different location, so, not in the stock, but in another place, that is virtual, not necessarily phisical.

I think you can try to sync your products in Woocommerce with the plugin Megainventory

So probably managing different kind of locations of the Products.

> You’ll be able to show in real-time your products’ availability in
> your WooCommerce frontend based on actual stock levels. You can
> connect more than one warehouses, stores or other types of locations
> at your disposal and the stock representation in the WooCommerce
> frontend will be correct.

Try to configure the Plugin Megainventory
https://woocommerce.com/document/how-to-integrate-woocommerce-with-megaventory/